# How to get the icon of an external app in a Flatpak GTK4 application

Tags: linux, gtk, pygobject, flatpak

I am developing an app which would require to get the icon of an installed app on the system.

My app is distributed as a Flatpak.

I tried `Gtk.Icon.new_from_icon_name()` but with no luck.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I don't understand how Flatpak works: my manifest included `"--filesystem=host"` but that was not enough

I added `"--filesystem=xdg-data/icons:ro"` and now it is working..